# Who is the shrewdest Shark?

Tags: shark-tank

The question is pretty simple, which *Shark Tank* investor has had the most success (and/or losses) from their *Shark Tank* investments? Ideally, I would like to see total dollars invested and their overall return on investment.

Is there a scorecard somewhere? Is that information available anywhere? I would like to know who the shrewdest Shark is on the show.

Comment: Some stats here: http://www.statisticbrain.com/shark-tank-investment-statistics/

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Very good! That was kind of the stuff  I was looking for. That's perfect. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. I don't think anyone will be able to find anything better. Although Dark Army's answer is pretty damn impressive when it comes to individual investments.

Answer (score 3):

Source [BusinessInsider](http://www.businessinsider.com/the-biggest-shark-tank-success-stories-2015-12) :

**Scrub Daddy** is the **Most successful** in shark tank investment.

Below is the list of 15 of the investors and their investments.

1.**Scrub Daddy**

> A sponge company has far and away become the biggest "Shark Tank" success story. Over the past three years, Scrub Daddy has brought in a total of $75 million in revenue, according to investor Lori Greiner.
>   Greiner made a deal with its founder and CEO, Aaron Krause, in Season 4 for $200,000 in exchange for 20% equity. At that point, Krause had struggled to reach $100,000 in sales over 18 months, but Greiner saw great potential in the company's signature offering, a proprietary smiley-faced sponge that was more durable, hygienic, and effective than a traditional one.
>   She helped Krause expand his product line and brought them onto QVC and into stores like Bed, Bath & Beyond, where they have become bestsellers.

2.**Tipsy Elves**

> When Robert Herjavec invested $100,000 for 10% of Evan Mendelsohn and
>   Nick Morton's ugly Christmas-sweater company in Season 4, it could
>   seem to viewers that he was betting on a fleeting fad. It turned out,
>   though, to be his most profitable "Shark Tank" investment, he told
>   Business Insider.
>
> To stay ahead of trends, Herjavec helped make Tipsy Elves a year-round
>   novelty apparel company that can capitalize off multiple holidays and
>   college-football season.
>
> Before its 2013 "Shark Tank" appearance, Tipsy Elves made $900,000 in
>   annual revenue. Last year it brought in around $8 million, and this
>   year it's on track to make $12 million, according to the company.

3.**Breathometer**

> In Season 5, Charles Yim got a five-Shark deal for Breathometer, a
>   portable Breathalyzer that works with a smartphone. Mark Cuban, Kevin
>   O'Leary, Daymond John, Herjavec, and Greiner got in on a $650,000 deal
>   for 30% of the company.
>
> Since his "Shark Tank" appearance, Yim secured an additional $6.5
>   million in funding, partnered with the prestigious Cleveland Clinic,
>   and developed a more accurate and more portable main product in
>   addition to a device that tracks oral health and hydration levels.
>
> Yim told Inc. that Breathometer is expected to end 2015 with $20
>   million in sales — double last year's number.

4.**Bubba's-Q Boneless Ribs**

> Al "Bubba" Baker, 1978 NFL Defensive Rookie of the Year, secured a
>   deal with John in Season 5 for $300,000 in exchange for 30% equity in
>   and licensing rights to his company, Bubba's-Q Boneless Ribs.
>
> John told Business Insider that as someone who built a career in
>   fashion, he never expected that his most profitable investment would
>   be in a rib business.
>
> John helped Baker secure a deal with a large-scale food processing
>   plant and said he thinks he can soon get Bubba's-Q to become a
>   national brand with $200 million in lifetime sales.

5.**Grace and Lace**

> In Season 5, Barbara Corcoran invested $175,000 for 10% of
>   husband-and-wife duo Melissa and Rick Hinnant's fashion company Grace
>   and Lace. Corcoran told Business Insider that it's her most profitable
>   "Shark Tank" investment.
>
> Before their appearance, the Hinnants brought in about $1 million in
>   sales. They are now expecting $6.5 million this year, a boost helped
>   by an appearance in Cosmopolitan magazine.
>
> As the company has grown, its philanthropic mission has as well, and
>   since appearing on the show it has used profits to open two orphanages
>   in India, housing a total of 100 kids.

6.**Ten Thirty One Productions**

> In Season 5, Cuban decided to put up $2 million for 20% of Melissa
>   Carbone's live horror-entertainment company Ten Thirty One
>   Productions.
>
> Last year the company brought in $3 million in revenue, and although
>   he did not disclose an exact number, Cuban told us it is making at
>   least half a million dollars in annual profit.
>
> Ten Thirty One had another successful Halloween season this year in
>   its birthplace of Los Angeles, but struggled in its expansion to New
>   York City due to a lack of preparation for storm conditions. Carbone
>   said it was a stressful but valuable learning experience, and she
>   looks forward to expanding to Cuban's hometown, Dallas, next year.

7. **Wicked Good Cupcakes**

> Tracey Noonan and Danielle Vilagie are a mother-daughter duo from
>   Boston with a company that makes cupcakes in a jar. In Season 4, they
>   made a deal with O'Leary in which he invested $75,000 for royalties
>   instead of equity. He made $1 from every cupcake sold until he made
>   his money back, and then began receiving 50 cents per cupcake sold.
>
> Since its appearance on the show, Wicked Good Cupcakes has expanded to
>   a new production facility and a couple of new locations.
>
> O'Leary said it's been his most profitable investment of the show, and
>   since Noonan and Vilagie appeared, they've gone from around $7,000 in
>   monthly sales to $400,000, or about $4.8 million annually.

8. **Red Dress Boutique**

> Cuban and Herjavec split a $1.2 million investment for 10% equity in
>   Diana and Josh Harbour's online women's fashion retailerThe Red Dress
>   Boutique in Season 6, with Cuban taking the lead advisory role.
>
> In the week following their television appearance, the
>   husband-and-wife team brought in $1 million in sales, but also
>   couldn't keep up with demand. Cuban helped them with infrastructure
>   issues, and last year they brought in $14 million in revenue.
>
> Cuban said it's making at least half a million dollars in annual
>   profit.

9. **Bombas**

> In Season 6, Bombas cofounders gave John a 17.5% stake in their
>   company for $200,000. It is an online-only athletic sock company that
>   donates a pair of socks to a homeless shelter for every pair sold.
>
> Bombas' founders told radio host Jason Baxthat they sold $400,000 of
>   socks in the four days after their television appearance and ended
>   2014 with $2 million in sales.
>
> John said it is one of his most profitable investments.

10. **Simple Sugars**

> Lani Lazzari was just 18 when she entered the tank in Season 4 to
>   pitch her skincare company Simple Sugars. She ended up making a deal
>   with Cuban for $100,000 in return for 33% equity.
>
> Within just 24 hours of her episode's premiere, Lazzari's sales jumped
>   to $220,000 from $50,000, and she hit $1 million six weeks later.
>   Today Simple Sugars products are in more than 700 retail locations and
>   ship internationally.
>
> Last year the company brought in more than $3 million in revenue, and
>   Cuban said it's one of his most profitable investments from the show.

11. **GrooveBook​**

> Husband-and-wife team Brian and Julie Whiteman came into the tank in
>   Season 3 to present GrooveBook, a digital-photo subscription service.
>   For $2.99 a month, users get a bound book of high-resolution photos
>   they took with their smartphones. The founders made a deal with Cuban
>   and O'Leary for $150,000 in exchange for 80% of licensing profits,
>   with O'Leary taking the lead advisory role.
>
> Not only did the Whitemans gain 50,000 subscribers shortly after the
>   premiere of their episode, but last November, the publicly traded
>   company Shutterfly bought GrooveBook for $14.5 million.

12. **Cousins Maine Lobster**

> Cousins Sabin Lomac and Jim Tselikis shipped lobster from their home
>   state of Maine to their new home in California and started a high-end
>   food truck named Cousins Maine Lobster, which became known for its
>   lobster rolls. The cousins made a deal with Corcoran for $55,000 in
>   exchange for 15% of their company in Season 4.
>
> Shortly after their episode premiered, the company hit $700,000 in
>   sales. Last year they brought in $8 million in revenue,according to
>   Entrepreneur.

13. **Bottle Breacher**

> Former Navy SEAL Eli Crane and his wife and business partner Jen made
>   a deal with Cuban and O'Leary for $150,000 in exchange for a 20% stake
>   in Bottle Breacher, a company staffed by military veterans who turn
>   dummy .50-caliber bullets into stylized bottle openers.
>
> O'Leary has taken the lead brand ambassador role and said it's one of
>   his most profitable investments. It's continued to grow to meet
>   increasing demand, and has made more than $2.5 million in sales this
>   year.

14. **Lumio**

> Herjavec invested $350,000 for 10% of Max Gunawan's foldable,
>   magnetic-lamp company Lumio in Season 6 after calling him "possibly
>   the best entrepreneur" he had seen so far on the show.
>
> Last year Lumio made $3 million in sales, hitting that mark again this
>   past June, he told Forbes. He explained that his growth is healthy and
>   that he will continue to make distribution deals with stores that
>   appeal to a high-end, artistic audience.

15. **ReadeRest**

> Rick Hopper essentially handed the reins of ReadeRest over to Greiner
>   when he agreed to a $150,000 investment in exchange for 65% of the
>   company in Season 3, but it turned his little one-man show into a huge
>   success.
>
> The product, a magnetic clip that holds eyeglasses in place on a
>   shirt, regularly sells out on QVC. Last year, Hopper said that he's
>   made over $8 million in total sales since his "Shark Tank" appearance.

Comment: +1 Although not exactly what I'm looking for (the most successful investor (Shark) overall on the show), nevertheless, this is a very interesting to see which individual products have done the best. Thank you.